# Why the timestamp parsed by YAML is not correct?

Tags: java, date, locale, yaml

Yaml file:

```
!!test.User
timestamp: 2012-11-22T01:02:03.567Z
```

Java class:

```
package test;

public class User {
    public Date timestamp;
}
```

Parse it with [snakeyaml](http://www.snakeyaml.org):

```
String str = "2012-11-22T01:02:03.567Z";

// parse it manually
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(str);
System.out.println("manually: " + date);

// parse it by snakeyaml
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.yaml");
User myUser = yaml.loadAs(input, User.class);
System.out.println("by Yaml: " + user.timestamp);
```

It prints:

```
manually: Thu Nov 22 01:02:03 CST 2012
by Yaml: Thu Nov 22 09:02:03 CST 2012
```

You can see they are different. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manual method gets the time in the current time zone, but it is actually expressed in UTC (as indicated by the `Z` time zone). So actually the value parsed by Yaml seems to be the correct one.

I am puzzled about the actual value though, CST (Central Standard Time USA) should be 6 hours behind UTC, but you get 8 hours ahead.

Comment: Unless it's China Standard Time.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski good point, I hate it when different time zones have the same abbreviation :-(

Comment: Which is why one should avoid the 3-letter time zone codes and instead use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Example: `America/Chicago` or `Asia/Taipei` instead of "CST".